# Dagger2 + Android multi module + instrumentation test + module override

Tags: android, dependency-injection, mocking, dagger-2, android-instrumentation

I'm migrating a project into a multi module architecture, but can't find a way to migrate the tests.

To keep it simple, let's say there are 3 modules:

`app` (com.android.application)

`core` (com.android.library)

`feature` (com.android.library)

`app`'s gradle includes `core` and `feature`

`feature` includes `core`

---

`core` contains the `Application` class, and a main `Component`

```
// MyApplication.kt
class MyApplication : Application {
    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        DaggerMainComponent.create()
    }
}

// MainComponent.kt
@Component(modules = [MainModule::class])
class MainComponent {
  fun provideSomething(): Something
}
```

---

`feature` has its own `Component`

```
// FeatureComponent.kt
@Component(module = [FeatureModule::class], dependencies = [MainComponent::class])
class FeatureComponent {
    fun inject(activity: FeatureActivity)
}

// FeatureActivity.kt
class FeatureActivity : Activity {
    override fun onCreate(@Nullable savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        DaggerFeatureComponent.builder()
            .mainComponent(mainComponent)
            .build()
            .inject(this)
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    }
}
```

---

Prior to the migration, there was only 1 component that could be overridden with test modules, during the test, using the `runner` trick.

My problem is how to use test modules while testing `FeatureActivity`? One way could be to have the `FeatureComponent` in `MyApplication` and use the same tactic. But ideally, feature components are not exposed. I've also tried to create providers to supply modules, and use `PowerMock` to override singleton/final classes.

Is there any elegant/standard way to achieve this? Thanks!

Comment: were you able to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can have an additional `testing` module (just for testing the `feature` module):

`feature-testing` (com.android.application)

Inside you can have a testing `Application` and supply testing modules however you want.

Comment: For the activity that uses its own component, how would you supply it from the test feature?